# Python 3.7 tuple to integer converter

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

```
import baseconvert, functools, operator
l = [120, 117, 114]
for i in l:
    li = baseconvert.base(i,10, 7)
    print (li)
```

How can I convert the result to integer in Python 3.7? `int(str(map(str, li)))` only gives 'str object is not callable'.

Comment: Are you using https://pypi.org/project/baseconvert/? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Yes, I am using baseconvert. I am expecting three integer numbers.

Comment: What do you mean "integer numbers"? You *start* with three numbers, but you're converting them into a base that Python doesn't support. Why don't you use the string option?

Comment: This is the output. (2, 3, 1)
(2, 2, 5)
(2, 2, 2) these are base7 numbers, but they can as well be represented with integers again.

Comment: The integers they represent *are your inputs*. If you mean you want 231, 225 and 222, why not just parse the string option with int? But this assumes base 10 (decimal) and loses the information that they're actually base 7 (..heptal?)

Comment: It is OK I lose the information. The problem is, the result of baseconvert is tuples of integers. int(li), map(str,li), ''.join(li) all don't work.